# How to solve `PrintDialog()` error in my case using ASP.Net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, printing

I am trying to print directly from CrystalReport using ASP.Net. Here is What I tried

**CS Code**

```
//header file
using System.Drawing.Printing;

PrinterSettings settings = new PrinterSettings();   //No error on this line
PrintDialog pdialog = new PrintDialog();            //error
if (pdialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        settings = pdialog.PrinterSettings;        //error
    }

_rdStudents.PrintToPrinter(settings, new PageSettings() { }, false);
```

**Error message**

> the type or namespace name 'printdialog' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or or assembly reference)

**Note**

I add `System.Printing dll` file on my project through reference -> Add reference

Comment: These type of code will only print on your server machine.

Comment: `using System.Windows.Controls` for PrintDialog.

Comment: To which **desktop window** is this dialog going to appear? You can't print using the *desktop viewer* in a *Web site*. If you want to print on the *user's printer*, add the ASP.NET report viewer and use its methods

Comment: @BensaysNotoPoliticsonSO on a web application?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Good point :-)

Comment: Where do you want this to print? Do you want the user to be able to print on his printer? Or do you want the server to print on a printer located where the server is located?

Comment: @Bensaysnotopoliticsonso I want to print in clinet pc

Comment: Then you need to either ask the browser to print from JavaScript, or generate a printable format like PDF and let the user download it.
Server can't tell the client PC to print.